# Can a StreamBuilder return List<Widget>

Tags: flutter, stream, rxdart

An `AppBar` in flutter takes `List<Widget>` as actions. For some reason, I can't find a way to feed this property based on a `StreamBuilder`.

I have a BehaviorSubject (can change to other types of stream) where I am adding Widgets and I want to show those widgets in the AppBar (as action buttons)

```dart
// ....

var appBar = new AppBar(
        title: "appTitle",
        actions: _getActionWidgets()   // <= Can be fed by SteamBuilder?
      )
/// ...


// ...
// BehaviorSubject<Widget> actionWidgets;
// ...

List<Widget> _getActionWidgets(){
  return StreamBuilder(
    ... // what can be done here so that this method would return List<Widget>
  );

}
```

Most of the examples out there are for "`ListView`" using the `ListView.builder(...)` which is not applicable in my case here.

The end goal is to feed the `actions` property of `AppBar` using StreamBuilder and struggling to find a way. I appreciate any help or directions and thanks for your time reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is not a case. Actions in your case are usually buttons (FlatButton, IconButton etc). Your case can looks like something below:

```dart
class Bloc {
  final _subject = BehaviourSubject<List<Widget>>();
  ...  
}
```

```dart
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // Prepare actions depending on condition
  final actions = [
    FlatButton(child: Text('Action 1'), onPressed: () {}),
    FlatButton(child: Text('Action 2'), onPressed: () {}),
  ];
  bloc.setActions(actions); // indeed send actions to sink
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<List<Widget>>(
    stream: bloc.actionStream, // Function of `bloc` which returns Stream<List<Widget>> (indeed IconButton, FlatButton)
    builder: (context,snapshot) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: snapshot.hasData? snapshot.data : <Widget>[],
        ),
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just fill `actions` with a single-element `List`, containing the `StreamBuilder` :

```dart
actions: [
    StreamBuilder(
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Row(children: [
                // Your widgets here
            ]);
        }
    ),
]
```

Comment: Thanks. It only showed the last widget on the list. Say I have two widgets, only the second one is visible. Can we show both (like append)?

Comment: You should return a `Row` within the `StreamBuilder`